# How could I queue KineticJS transitions?

Tags: queue, kineticjs, transition

I want to queue some kineticJS transitions with variable duration, for example:

```
scrub.transitionTo({
      x:400,
      duration: 4,
      callback: function() {

        console.log('complete 400');
        scrub.transitionTo({
        x:500,
        duration: 1,
        callback: function() {
          console.log('complete 100');
        }
      });

      }
    });
```

These are just two nested transitions of the same object, but I want to automate this procedure for 10 or more nested callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new object and place your transition data in it.

```
 var transition1 = {
     x:400,
     duration: 4,
     callback: function(){
        console.log('complete 400');
         ....
     }
 };

var transition2 = {
   x:500,
   duration: 1,
   callback: function() {
        console.log('complete 100');
   }
};
```

Then you can just create a while loop to call the transitions without a need for a callback.

But since you do want a callback, you need to create a function which the callback will call and a condition will be checked.

```
 function callFunction(scrub, numberOfExecutions){
     if(condition == myCondition){
         scrub.transitionTo(transition1);
         numberOfExecutions--;
     }
     else if(condition2 == myCondition2){
         scrub.transitionTo(transition2);
         numberOfExecutions--;
     }
     if(numberOfExecutions < 1) return 0;
     else return 0;
 };
```

As a note, it's not wise to do these nested recursive calls as some browsers will automatically think the scripts are stuck in an infinite loop and won't execute.

Comment: The problem here is that the x and duration are variables that will be changing, so there cannot be one or two objects with parameters, what I thought was to go with setTimeout on subsequent intervals, which kinda works but there is no way to stop() and resume() the transitions

Comment: so since every one of the parameters will be changing, will they be random values? or something specific? could use some more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: are you trying to do something like 'Shape Tango' on the KineticJS site? Where a bunch of shapes transition at one time? But you just want it do be done automatically rather than on button click?